# Managing Intents in Dialogflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, dialogflow-es

I want to know if there is some way through which I can manage, update or delete Intents in Dialogflow programmatically using python.

I have been able to send and get response from dialogflow using apiai library, but i want to be able to input intents, it's questions and the text response.

I went through dialogflow library, which i think does help with that, but it has some requirements on making account on google console clouds.

Is there a way to do what I want, without having to create/do billings or whatever it mentions in it's documentation in Dialogflow.

If there is, please point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The Dialogflow API is the only way for your to programmatically update an agent's intents and entities: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/

You will need to use a Google Account to create an agent to begin with. Billing shouldn't be needed to simply run an agent that doesn't use any other Google API's.